# Twitter style scrolling control for winforms

Tags: winforms, twitter, scroll, controls, feed

I'm sure you're all aware of the scrolling controls used in webpages that display Twitter feeds?

Well I want to acheive a similar effect in a winforms app, but can't work out how to do it, and don't even know if it can either be done, or has been done already in a custom control somewhere?.

Basically, I want the application to poll a datasource and check for new items. If a new item exists, then create a new entry for the control, scroll down the old entries and fade in the new entry at the top. Of course the new entry addition needs to look good, so smooth scrolling and fading are essential.

Does anyone know of an existing control that can do such a thing, or have any suggestion as to where I'd start?